# Trying to understand how asynchronous v3 google map loads

Tags: jquery, google-maps, asynchronous

I've built a full page slider (bxslider) website where I asynchronously load the "pages" that aren't the landing page slide.  One of those slides, the contact page slide, has three google maps to load via the v3 api.  Here is the code (with some massaging to handle bxslider's potential cloning of the contact page slide for infinite looping):

```
var maploaded = false;
var artemis_marker = '/images/custom_marker.png';
var map;
var styles = [{ stylers: [{ saturation: -100}]}];

function loadScript(src) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function initializeMaps() {
    $('.map').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass($(this).attr('rel'));
        var latlng = $(this).attr('latlng').replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\(/g, '').replace(/\)/g, '');
        var latlngarray = latlng.split(',');
        processmaps(parseFloat(latlngarray[0]), parseFloat(latlngarray[1]), $(this).attr('rel'));
    });
}

function initialize(obj, lat, lng) {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: location
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(obj, mapOptions);
    map.setOptions({ styles: styles });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: artemis_marker
    });
}

function processmaps(lat, lng, mapclass) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(mapclass);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(x[i], lat, lng));
    }
}

function setContactMaps() {
    if (!maploaded) {
        maploaded = true;
        loadScript('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initializeMaps');
    }
}
```

I've done a fair bit of reading about how to load google maps asynchronously, and I've implemented my version of it here, but it seems to me that it's not so much asyncronous in the sense that jquery's XMLHttpRequest() is if you set it to run asynchronously.  Instead, this "lazy loading" just seems to push the lag that loading google maps introduces "downstream" to wherever the actual loading is invoked.

In my case, when you click one of the contact location buttons on the contact page slide it triggers the loading of the api script and then the map.  But still, the overlay that I instantiate on click has a blank spot while the map slowly loads into the space (and slower still because I load all three maps on any button click because so far I've been too lazy to break it out to individual maps for individual button clicks).  Ideally, I'd have the maps load when you land on the contact page slide, but then the jquery hover effect I have on the buttons gets stuck and doesn't work while the maps are loading behind the scenes.

Is this because the jquery object that handles the hover effect is busy loading the map?  Is there a way to load google maps truly asynchronously like XMLHttpRequest() does?  Any other solutions to eliminate this map loading lag?

Comment: Not sure why you do `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(x[i], lat, lng));` inside a for loop. If you want to add multiple markers, you can just do `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...})`.

Comment: It's not for the markers.  Because I'm using bx-slider with infinite loop, there is the potential for a slide to be cloned and for the need for two instances of the same map to be produced.  That's why I do getElementsByClassName(), to grab all elements for that location in case one is in a cloned slide.